# I can't get data to be saved in an arrayList

Tags: java

I have a problem that I can't solve. I can't get the "Socio" objects to be saved in the ArrayList. After doing tests the data reaches its class, but I don't know why it isn't saved.

Below I've put both classes. It could possibly be done better, but I'm still learning. I need to save the data and display them in the main class.

A clarification: The members are created at the same time as the players because the players need to be members before.

```
public class Jugador extends Persona {

    private int dorsal = 0;
    private int NumPartidos = 0;
    
    //ArrayList
    private ArrayList<Partido> ListaPartidos;
    private ArrayList<Partido> Estadistica;
    private ArrayList<Jugador> ListaJugadores;
    
    private int PARTIDOS_TEMPORADA = 15; //Numero de temporadas
    private String temporada []= new String[PARTIDOS_TEMPORADA];

    //Constructor
    public Jugador(String nombre, String apellidos, String DNI, String CuentaBancaria,int dorsal,int NumPartidos) 
    {
        super(nombre, apellidos, DNI, CuentaBancaria);
        this.dorsal = dorsal;
        this.NumPartidos = NumPartidos;
        this.ListaPartidos = new ArrayList<Partido>();
        this.Estadistica = new ArrayList<Partido>();
        this.ListaJugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
    }
    
    //Constructor vacio
    public Jugador()
    {
        this.dorsal = 0;
        this.NumPartidos = 0;
        this.ListaPartidos = new ArrayList<Partido>();
        this.Estadistica = new ArrayList<Partido>();
        this.ListaJugadores = new ArrayList<Jugador>();
    }

    //Getters y setters
    public int getDorsal() {
        return dorsal;
    }

    public ArrayList<Partido>ListaPartidos() {
        return ListaPartidos;
    }
    
    public int getNumPartidos() {
        return NumPartidos;
    }

    public void setDorsal(int dorsal) 
    {
        this.dorsal = dorsal;
    }

    public void setListaPartidos(ArrayList<Partido> EstadisticaJugador)
    {
        
        this.ListaPartidos = EstadisticaJugador;
    }
    
    public void setNumPartidos(int numPartidos) 
    {
        this.NumPartidos = numPartidos;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Partido> getEstadistica() {
        return Estadistica;
    }

    public void setEstadistica(ArrayList<Partido> Estadistica) {
        this.Estadistica = Estadistica;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Jugador> getListaJugadores() {
        return ListaJugadores;
    }

    public void setListaJugadores(ArrayList<Jugador> listaJugadores) {
        ListaJugadores = listaJugadores;
    }
    
    //Metodo para crear objetos socios y jugadores.
    public void nuevoSocio() //Metodo para crear socios
    {
        String nombre,apellido,DNI,IBAN;
        int NumPartidos = 0;
        double cuota;
        
        

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) 
        {
            Socio socio = new Socio();
            
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Nombre: ");
            System.out.println(nombre = Persona.generarNombre());

            System.out.print("Apellido: ");
            System.out.println(apellido = Persona.generarApellido());

            System.out.print("DNI: ");
            System.out.println(DNI = Persona.generaDNI());

            System.out.print("Cuenta bancaria: ");
            System.out.println(IBAN = Persona.generaIBAN());

            System.out.print("Cuota de socio: ");
            System.out.println(cuota = Math.random()*(700 )+400); 

            System.out.print("Dorsal como jugador: ");
            System.out.println((this.dorsal++)+1);
            
            ListaJugadores.add(new Jugador(nombre,apellido,DNI,IBAN,dorsal,NumPartidos));
            
            Socio socioAux = new Socio(nombre,apellido,DNI,IBAN,cuota);
            
            socio.AgregarSocio(socioAux);
        }
    }
    
    //Metodo para comprobar el dorsal introducido sea valido
    //Ayudara a ver los datos exclusivos del dorsal escojido
    public Jugador ComprobarDorsal(int dorsal) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ListaJugadores.size(); i++) 
        {
            Jugador jugador = ListaJugadores.get(i);
                        
            if ( jugador.getDorsal() == dorsal)
            {
//              System.out.println(dorsalAux);
                return jugador;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    //Metodo que agregara un objeto partido en un arraylist
    public void AgregarPartido(Partido p, boolean participar)
    {
        if(participar)
        {
            this.NumPartidos++; //Sumara +1 al objeto jugador que haya partricipado en el partido.
            ListaPartidos.add(p);
        }
        else
        {
            ListaPartidos.add(p);
        }
    }
    
    public void AgregarEstadistica(Partido p)
    {
        this.Estadistica.add(p);
    }

    //Metodo que mostrara los partidos jugados y sus datos
    public void muestraPartidos(int dorsal) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.size(); i++)
        {
            if(ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getValObtenido() > -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre del equipo rival: " + ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNomEquipo());
                System.out.println("Minutos jugados: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getMinJugados());
                System.out.println("Puntos conseguidos: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getPunConseguidos());
                System.out.println("Rebotes: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumRebotes());
                System.out.println("Asistencias: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumAsistencias());
                System.out.println("Tapones: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumTapones());
                System.out.println("Valoracion obtenida: "+ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getValObtenido() + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    //Metodo que mostrara la estadistica de cada jugador en los partidos jugados
    public void mostrarEstadisticas(int dorsal) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.size(); i++)
        {
            if(ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getValObtenido() > -1)
            {
                System.out.println("Nombre del equipo rival: " + ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNomEquipo());
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de minutos jugados: " + (ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getMinJugados()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getMinJugados() +"%");
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de puntos conseguidos: "+(ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getPunConseguidos()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getPunConseguidos() + "%");
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de rebotes: " + (ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumRebotes()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getNumRebotes() +  "%");
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de asistencias: " + (ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumAsistencias()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getNumAsistencias() + "%");
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de tapones: " + (ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getNumTapones()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getNumTapones() +"%");
                System.out.println("Porcentaje de valoracion obtenida: " + (ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).ListaPartidos.get(i).getValObtenido()*100)/ComprobarDorsal(dorsal).Estadistica.get(i).getValObtenido() + "%\n");

            }
            
        }
    }
    
    public void nuevoPartido()  //Metodo que permitira jugar la temporada de 15 partidos
    {
        int minJugados, puntosOb, rebotes, asistencias, tapones = 0, valoracionOb;

        if (ListaJugadores.size() == 0)
        {
            System.err.println("No hay jugadores para jugar partidos");
        }
        else if(ListaJugadores.size() < 10)
        {
            System.err.println("Se necesitan minimo 10 jugadores. Actualmente hay: " + ListaJugadores.size() + " jugadores.");
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0;i<PARTIDOS_TEMPORADA;i++) 
            {
                {
                    int minJugadosTotal = 0,puntosObTotal = 0,rebotesTotal = 0,
                            asistenciasTotal = 0,taponesTotal = 0,valoracionObTotal = 0;

                    System.out.println("\nPartido "+(i+1));
                    //              String nomEquipo = ent.nextLine();
                    String nomEquipo = Partido.nombresEquipos();

                    System.out.println("Nombre del equipo rival: " + nomEquipo);

                    temporada[i] = nomEquipo;

                    for (int j = 0; j < ListaJugadores.size(); j++) //Se guarda la informacion de cada partido en cada jugador
                    {
                        Jugador jugadorAux = ListaJugadores.get(j);

                        //booleano que segun el numero, se encontrara en un estado u otro
                        boolean participacion;
                        Random random = new Random(); //Se genera un booleano random para hacer si un jugador ha jugado o no un partido
                        participacion = random.nextBoolean();

                        minJugados = (int)(Math.random()*60+1);

                        puntosOb = (int)(Math.random()*45+1);

                        rebotes = (int)(Math.random()*15+1);

                        asistencias = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);

                        tapones = (int)(Math.random()*10+1);

                        valoracionOb = (int)(Math.random()*50+1);


                        if(participacion) //Siempre que el booleano sea true se guardaran los datos del partido
                        {
                            participacion = true;
                            jugadorAux.AgregarPartido(new Partido(nomEquipo, minJugados, puntosOb, rebotes, asistencias, 
                                    tapones, valoracionOb),participacion);

                            //Se guardara por cada partido jugado, el valor de todos los jugadores, se utilizara para comprobar la estadistica de cada jugador
                            
                            minJugadosTotal += minJugados;

                            puntosObTotal += puntosOb;

                            rebotesTotal += rebotes;

                            asistenciasTotal += asistencias;

                            taponesTotal += tapones;

                            valoracionObTotal += valoracionOb;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            participacion = false;
                            jugadorAux.AgregarPartido(new Partido("", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1),participacion); //Se guardan datos en negativo, para que no cuenta como partido jugado
                        }
                    }
                    for (int k = 0; k < this.ListaJugadores.size(); k++) //Se guarda por cada jugador, el total de la estadistica de cada partido.
                    {
                        Jugador jugadorAux = ListaJugadores.get(k);
                        jugadorAux.AgregarEstadistica(new Partido(nomEquipo,minJugadosTotal,puntosObTotal,rebotesTotal,asistenciasTotal,taponesTotal,valoracionObTotal));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void mayorParticipacion() //Calcula el jugador con mayor participacion. Devuelve el dorsal del jugador con mayor participacion
    {
        int NumPartidos = 0;
        int dorsal = 0;
        String nombre = "",apellido = "";
        for (int i = 0;i<this.ListaJugadores.size();i++) 
        {
            if(this.ListaJugadores.get(i).NumPartidos >= NumPartidos)
            {
                NumPartidos = ListaJugadores.get(i).getNumPartidos();
                dorsal = ListaJugadores.get(i).getDorsal();
                nombre = ListaJugadores.get(i).getNombre();
                apellido = ListaJugadores.get(i).getApellidos();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nEl jugador con mayor participacion: " + NumPartidos + "\nNombre: " + nombre + "\nApellido: " + apellido + "\nDorsal: " + dorsal+"\n");
    }

    public void mayorPuntuacion() //Calcula el jugador con mayor participacion. Devuelve el dorsal del jugador con mayor puntuacion
    {
        int puntuacion = 0;
        int dorsal = 0;
        String nombre = "",apellido = "";
        for (int i = 0;i<this.ListaJugadores.size();i++) 
        {
            Jugador jugador = ListaJugadores.get(i);
            if(jugador.getEstadistica().get(i).getValObtenido() > puntuacion)
            {
                puntuacion = jugador.getEstadistica().get(i).getPunConseguidos();
                dorsal = ListaJugadores.get(i).getDorsal();
                nombre = ListaJugadores.get(i).getNombre();
                apellido = ListaJugadores.get(i).getApellidos();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nEl jugador con mayor puntuacion: " + puntuacion + "\nNombre: " + nombre + "\nApellido: " + apellido + "\nDorsal: " + dorsal+"\n");
    }

    public void mayorValoracion() //Calcula el jugador con mayor participacion. Devuelve el dorsal del jugador con mayor puntuacion
    {
        double valoracion = 0;
        int dorsal = 0;
        String nombre = "",apellido = "";
        for (int i = 0;i<this.ListaJugadores.size();i++) 
        {
            Jugador jugador = ListaJugadores.get(i);
            if(jugador.getEstadistica().get(i).getValObtenido() > valoracion)
            {
                valoracion = jugador.getEstadistica().get(i).getValObtenido();
                dorsal = ListaJugadores.get(i).getDorsal();
                nombre = ListaJugadores.get(i).getNombre();
                apellido =ListaJugadores.get(i).getApellidos();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\nEl jugador con mayor valoracion: " + valoracion + "\nNombre: " + nombre + "\nApellido: " + apellido + "\nDorsal: " + dorsal+"\n");
    }
    
    public Jugador buscarJugador(int dorsal) //Funcion que servira para comprobar segun el dorsal introducido los datos de los partidos jugados
    {
        for (int i = 0;i<this.ListaJugadores.size();i++) 
        {
            if(ListaJugadores.get(i).getDorsal() == dorsal)
            {
                return ListaJugadores.get(i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    public String toString ()
    {
        return "Nombre del jugador: "+this.getNombre() + "\nApellidos: "+this.getApellidos()+"\nDNI: "
                +this.getDNI()+"\nDorsal: "+(this.getDorsal()) + "\nHa jugado: "+this.getNumPartidos() + "\n";
    }
}

public class Socio extends Persona{

    private final double cuota;
    private ArrayList<Socio> ListaSocios;

    public Socio(String nombre, String apellidos, String DNI, String CuentaBancaria, double cuota) 
    {
        super(nombre, apellidos, DNI, CuentaBancaria);
        this.cuota = cuota;
        this.ListaSocios = new ArrayList<Socio>();
    }
    
    public Socio()
    {
        this.cuota = 0;
        this.ListaSocios = new ArrayList<Socio>();
    }

    //Los getters y setters
    public double getCuota() {
        return cuota;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Socio> getListaSocios() {
        return ListaSocios;
    }

    public void setListasocios(ArrayList<Socio> listaSocios) {
        this.ListaSocios = listaSocios;
    }
    
    public void AgregarSocio(Socio s)
    {
        this.ListaSocios.add(s);
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "\nNombre: "+this.getNombre()+"\nApellidos: "+this.getApellidos()+"\nDNI: "+this.getDNI()
                + "\nCuota: "+this.getCuota()+"\nCuentaBancaria: "+this.getCuentaBancaria() + "\n";
    }
}
```

I have modified the Socio class and it still doesn't work (NEW CHANGES)

```
public class Socio extends Persona{

    private double cuota;
    private ArrayList<Socio> ListaSocios = new ArrayList<Socio>();

    public Socio(String nombre, String apellidos, String DNI, String CuentaBancaria, double cuota) 
    {
        super(nombre, apellidos, DNI, CuentaBancaria);
        this.cuota = cuota;
    }
    
    public Socio()
    {
        this.cuota = 0;
    }

    //Los getters y setters
    public double getCuota() {
        return cuota;
    }


    public void setCuota(double cuota) 
    {
        
        this.cuota = cuota;
    }


    public ArrayList<Socio> getListaSocios() 
    {
        return this.ListaSocios;
    }

    public void setListaSocios(ArrayList<Socio> listaSocios) 
    {
        this.ListaSocios = listaSocios;
    }

     public void AgregarSocio(Socio s)
    {

        Socio socioAux = new Socio(s.getNombre(),s.getApellidos(),s.getDNI(),s.getCuentaBancaria(),s.getCuota());
        
        System.out.println(socioAux.toString());
        
        ListaSocios.add(socioAux);
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        return "\nNombre: "+this.getNombre()+"\nApellidos: "+this.getApellidos()+"\nDNI: "+this.getDNI()
                + "\nCuota: "+this.getCuota()+"\nCuentaBancaria: "+this.getCuentaBancaria() + "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is difficult to read: variable names begin lower case in Java: https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions
But your design is also wrong. `Socio` should not contain a list of itself. That's the responsibility of another class. Where is the code that's "saving" `Socio`s? The same design problem applies to `Jugador` and it's worse still there, as every time you create an instance, you are creating the collections the class encapsulates (probably incorrectly). Why are you doing that?

Comment: Incidentally, the problem you mention will be the result of what I mentioned about the collections, but that's actually not *really* the problem. The *real* problem is an incorrect design

Comment: So I need to create a class that contains all the lists?

Comment: In your for loop you create a new `Socio` instance each iteration: `Socio socio = new Socio();` but this instance is not stored anywhere, it is discarded.

Comment: You should probably tell us about the large picture of what your software needs to model

Comment: The idea is to create a program that creates players, partners and workers, the players must be partners. Then they will play a season that is 15 games and at the end they must show the number of games played, the statistics of each player, as well as once the partners/workers/players have been created, to be able to see their data. Apart from these classes that I have taught, I have 4 more, the main one is a menu.

Comment: OK. The application class can have `List<Jugador>` for *all* players but the game class (I hope there is one) could also have that type to hold the players. If there are only two players per game if could have two separate instances of `Jugador`

Comment: I have make the changes and works!! i show you de class, i know its weird to see, but im a noob in this. Thanks you for your time <3

Comment: No problem. Just remember - coding only starts when you have the design fully worked out